# Hidden input value should be changed when selecting a item from drop box in laravel 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5

Here is my drop box and then after the hidden box. These are inside the form.

```
 <tr>
     <td> <b>{!! Form::label('Types', 'Type') !!}</b></td>

     <td> {!! Form::select('type', array('type' => 'type','Orange' => 'Orange', 'Red' => 'Red','Green' => 'Green'), 'type') !!}</td>
</tr>

{!! Form::hidden('color') !!}
```

Script is below after the form.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#type').on('change', function () {
            $('#color').val($(this).val());

        });

    });
</script>
```

Hidden input value get empty after the execution. Where am I wrong. Please can you help that out for me?

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: No. not setting the value for hidden field

Comment: The code is fine. Can you reproduce that error in a fiddle or something?

Comment: No any errors. I just need to know where am I wrong about setting the value for hidden field according to selected value of drop box

Comment: No issue when recreated in a sandbox: http://www.bootply.com/timCf3P7UY Check that the html generated by the `Form::` commands is accurate, or don't use the `Form::` commands and just write html. `<select id="type">`, `<input type="hidden" id="color"/>`, etc etc

Answer (score 0):

Try to select the list by name as :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[name="type"]').on('change', function () {
        $('#color').val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Because you don't have `ids` (`#type`,`#Orange`, `#Red`, `#Green`) in your code since `Form::select` will just generate a select tag with name `type` and options that have values and not `ids`, like following :

```
<select name='type'>
     <option value='type'>type</option>
     <option value='Orange'>Orange</option>
     <option value='Red'>Red</option>
     <option value='Green'>Green</option>
</select>
```

So you're trying to attach `change` event to elements who aren't presented in your DOM.

---

Or you could add the `id` using :

```
{!! Form::select('type', array(...), 'type', ['id' => 'type']) !!}
```

Then you will be able to use `id` selector :

```
$('#type').on('change', function () {
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this

```
{!! Form::select('type', array('type' => 'type','Orange' => 'Orange', 'Red' => 'Red','Green' => 'Green'), 'type', ['id' => 'type']) !!}
```

and you need to change your hidden field to this

```
{!! Form::hidden('color', '', ['id' => 'color']) !!}
```

Laravel Form::select only adds name to tag not id. Since your jquery is selecting by ID you can't grab the value from the option box.

Comment: Still it is not setting a value for hidden field because I return an empty value

Comment: the hidden field also needs an ID attribute. If you set your pulldown to a value it should fill in the hidden field. Are you using the browser's developer console? You can write values to the console on select or simply use an alert box.

Comment: I tried it on my current laravel project and it works.

Comment: For the hidden field not set the value.